# xargs and echo limited number of replacements

Tags: command-line, bash, xargs, echo, macos-ventura

I want to duplicate some text a few times.
Xargs doesn't do more than 5 items.
I don't know if there is a better way to do this.

```
echo "sometext " | xargs -n 9 -t -I RRRR echo  RRRR RRRR RRRR RRRR RRRR RRRR RRRR
echo sometext sometext sometext sometext sometext RRRR RRRR
sometext sometext sometext sometext sometext RRRR RRRR
```

Ultimately this should end up in print to build some commands that need the same text in different places.

```
echo "sometext " | xargs  -t -I RRRR printf " cmd1 %s cmd2 %s cmd3 %s cmd4 %s  cmd5 %s cmd6 %s cmd7 %s"  RRRR RRRR RRRR RRRR RRRR RRRR RRRR
printf  cmd1 %s cmd2 %s cmd3 %s cmd4 %s  cmd5 %s cmd6 %s cmd7 %s sometext sometext sometext sometext sometext RRRR RRRR
cmd1 sometext cmd2 sometext cmd3 sometext cmd4 sometext  cmd5 sometext cmd6 RRRR cmd7 RRRR⏎
```

After the fifth parameter, xargs stops doing replacements.

```
echo "sometext " | xargs -n 9000  -t -I RRRR printf " cmd1 %s cmd2 %s cmd3 %s cmd4 %s  cmd5 %s cmd6 %s cmd7 %s"  RRRR RRRR RRRR RRRR RRRR RRRR RRRR
printf  cmd1 %s cmd2 %s cmd3 %s cmd4 %s  cmd5 %s cmd6 %s cmd7 %s sometext sometext sometext sometext sometext RRRR RRRR
cmd1 sometext cmd2 sometext cmd3 sometext cmd4 sometext  cmd5 sometext cmd6 RRRR cmd7 RRRR⏎
```

I tried to use -n and -L options but they didn't work either.

```
echo "sometext " | xargs -L 1 -t -I RRRR printf " cmd1 %s cmd2 %s cmd3 %s cmd4 %s  cmd5 %s cmd6 %s cmd7 %s"  RRRR RRRR RRRR RRRR RRRR RRRR RRRR
printf  cmd1 %s cmd2 %s cmd3 %s cmd4 %s  cmd5 %s cmd6 %s cmd7 %s sometext sometext sometext sometext sometext RRRR RRRR
cmd1 sometext cmd2 sometext cmd3 sometext cmd4 sometext  cmd5 sometext cmd6 RRRR cmd7 RRRR⏎
```

My os details

```
xargs version
macOS 13.2                                                                                                                   
August 4, 2015                                                                                                                   
macOS 13.2
```

Comment: (1) The [POSIX specification of `xargs`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) states that "at least five arguments […] can each contain one or more instances of `replstr`". This probably means there is or was a major implementation that cannot do six. I guess you've found it. (2) "to build some commands that need the same text in different places" – Have you considered a shell function where you use `"$1"` multiple times? Is `xargs` a must? (3) Your "question" is a story, not a question. What are you asking? "Why?", "how to fix?", "any alternative?"? What?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you're doing, but `xargs` is probably the wrong solution.

A simple way in `bash` would be

```
for i in $(seq 1 10) ; do
    echo -n "sometext "
    if [ $i = 10 ] ; then
        echo
    fi
done
```

Or

```
yes sometext | head -11 | paste -sd' '
```

Or, if you really like `xargs`:

```
echo sometext | xargs yes 2>/dev/null | head -12 | paste -sd' '
```